# Correcting topological errors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, topology

Using the topological corrector inside Qgis I have identified overlapping polygons. My situation is represented into this image
[image]

My polygon of interest is located below another polygon (the red polygon). I would like to correct this error, however I can't select the red polygon to delete.

Do you have any other idea to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is not that you can't select a polygon. Instead, the problem is that you can't *see* that you've selected a polygon. The red highlighting from the Topology Checker covers up the yellow highlighting from the selection tool.

In this example, the smaller polygon is selected, but you can't see the yellow highlight because it's entirely hidden by the red-highlighted error.

[image]

Once I turn off "show errors," you can see that the smaller polygon is highlighted.

[image]

In this example, you can see that one of these polygons is selected because part of the selected polygon extends beyond the red-highlighted area of overlap.

[image]

**Try turning off "show errors" on the Topology Checker panel.** This makes it easier to see which polygons are selected.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!